# What ee ecommerce modules allow for product import?

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, brilliantretail

What EE ecommerce modules allow for product import?

I want to use an Excel doc, save it as a CSV, for example.

I only have about six fields - Title, Number, Price, Image, Pkg Quantity, Weight.

I have about 600 products, will eventually be 3,000.

This would be an EE 3 site but I could still use EE 2 if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

[Cartthrob](https://www.cartthrob.com/) is the defacto standard for commerce within EE3. It uses standard channels for product info which allows you to then use [datagrab](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) which you can configure to import your product data. Import once, set Cron jobs to import regularly, use CSV, json or XML as your source.

Plenty of resources around for formatting data to import correctly.